# VB6 application from network share

Tags: networking, vb6

My vb6 application starts faster under safe mode from network share than under normal mode.
Why?

I have atheros 100mbit nic and windows 7 x32.

Comment: The reason for this sort of issue, in general, not specific to VB6, is often references to not currently available network names and paths, the errors for which are eventually ignored but timeouts need to be waited for.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm running under "Safe Mode with networking", so network paths and names are available.

Comment: I mean any network paths that may be assumed to not be present in safe mode are not assumed so normally. But in any case try something like [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see if you can see what is failing/timing out when you run normally compared to safe mode.